# How to acknowledge a Docusign Connect event

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working with Docusign Connect and receiving events happily. Recently I was looking at the docs and noticed the `requireAcknowledgement` flag and I'm trying to implement that with mixed success. Normally, when I receive a Connect Event, I return a 200 with an empty body. But after flipping that flag, events are falling into the Connect failures log with the error message: `"error": "https://scrubbed/ :: Error - Envelope Id returned does not match, returned data: 200 OK"`

So, in order of diagnostics:

- Docusign Connect is generally working fine, I receive events and send back an empty 200
- When I flip the `requireAcknowledgement` boolean, all events fall into the Connect failures log with an error about an envelope id not matching. Since I don't send back an envelope id in the body, that seems correct
- I can't find docs about how I should specify the envelope id in the acknowledgement. Is it a header? Is it xml in the body? Is it json? Is it just the first string encountered?
- If I turn off `requireAcknowledgement` I can get status changes again with no other changes.

Here's my Connect Config:

```
{
  "connectId": "xxx",
  "urlToPublishTo": "https://{snip}/",
  "name": "POST everything to test webhook",
  "allowEnvelopePublish": "true",
  "enableLog": "true",
  "includeDocuments": "false",
  "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false",
  "requiresAcknowledgement": "true",
  "signMessageWithX509Certificate": "true",
  "useSoapInterface": "false",
  "includeTimeZoneInformation": "true",
  "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
  "includeSenderAccountasCustomField": "true",
  "envelopeEvents": "Sent,Delivered,Signed,Completed,Declined,Voided",
  "recipientEvents": "Sent,Delivered,Completed,Declined",
  "soapNamespace": "",
  "allUsers": "true",
  "includeCertSoapHeader": "false"
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this while trolling through the connect logs. Docusign has their own connect config and this was a response that they sent back as confirmation (to themselves). There's probably a plain xml version as well, but I don't know.

Note: This is not usually required, only if you're using the requireAcknowledgement flag. The point is to prove to Docusign that not only did you get the data, but you were able to parse it and get some values out. So it's helpful if you're worried about corruption or about your servers failing for some reason.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:response>
      <EnvelopeID>xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</EnvelopeID>
    </soap:response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am implementing the DocuSign Connect using SOAP. So do I need to send the response back in excatly the above format?

Comment: I believe you do. We were using the JSON api and we still had to send back this exact xml snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The DocuSign SDK has a good example of how responses should be returned, that's what I've used for the base of my Connect Listener and had great success (using the .NET version).

IIRC `envelopeId` isn't a requirement for standard Connect events, only for `useSoapInterface`, which you have set to false.

---

## Sample Code taken from the SDK

> ### .ASPX Page
>
> ```
> <form id="form1" runat="server">
> <div>
>     <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
> </div>
> </form>
> ```
>
> ### .ASPX.CS  Page
>
> ```
> this.statusLabel.Text = "All is well. Wrote " + envelopeInfo.DocumentPDFs.Length + " documents";
> ```

[DocuSign SDK - .NET Connect Code](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/tree/master/MS.NET/Connect)

Comment: It's the requireAcknowledgement flag that means I have to return an envelope id. But I did find a response eventually. Turns out the default docusign connect config sent a response that I was able to spy on. Answer is below.